# Datatables backend not working

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I have staging and live environment for my project. On staging env my code is working fine, but on live it's not working. (both servers have php 5.6 running)

My problem is that Datatables Editor backend script is returning blank white page without errors. I have tested that if I have small amount of records in DB ( like 5-10 records ), it's loading everything right.

Backend script:

```
<?php

include( "../classes/datatables/DataTables.php" );

// Alias Editor classes so they are easy to use
use
    DataTables\Editor,
    DataTables\Editor\Field,
    DataTables\Editor\Format,
    DataTables\Editor\Mjoin,
    DataTables\Editor\Options,
    DataTables\Editor\Upload,
    DataTables\Editor\Validate;

// Build our Editor instance and process the data coming from _POST
Editor::inst( $db, 'translate' )
    ->fields(
        Field::inst( 'id' ),
        Field::inst( 'alias' )->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' ),
        Field::inst( 'lv' ),
        Field::inst( 'ru' ),
        Field::inst( 'en' ),
        Field::inst( 'translated' )
        ->setFormatter( function ( $val, $data, $opts ) {
                return ! $val ? 0 : 1;
            } )
    )
    ->process( $_POST )
    ->json();
```

am I missing any php library I don't know, what could be a problem?

Comment: are you sure that all dependencies are downloaded in your live env ?

Comment: I mean that you may missed out running the `composer install` in your live app for example

Comment: Yes, all dependencies are loaded. (Because other pages datatables are loading fine)

I am not using composer for my app.I think that this is some library related, or mysql related :(

Comment: did you see error in browser console and php log ?

Comment: @inye There are no errors in browser console and php error logs also are empty which is very strange. http://prntscr.com/frzajf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OMG! Took 2 days and found solution, needed to add "charset=utf8" to dsn!

```
$sql_details = array(
"type" => "Mysql",  // Database type: "Mysql", "Postgres", "Sqlserver", "Sqlite" or "Oracle"
"user" => DB_LOGIN,       // Database user name
"pass" => DB_PASS,       // Database password
"host" => DB_HOST,       // Database host
"port" => 3306,       // Database connection port (can be left empty for default)
"db"   => DB_DB,       // Database name
"dsn"  => "charset=utf8"        // PHP DSN extra information. Set as `charset=utf8` if you are using MySQL
);
```